# I Accidentally Forgot To Check "Delete the driver software for this device" When Uninstalling My Bluetooth Driver

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, bluetooth, device-manager

So my Bluetooth driver randomly stopped working and restarting didn't fix it so I uninstalled my Bluetooth driver but I forgot check "Delete the driver software for this device" and now that I've reinstalled the driver from https://www.msi.com/Laptop/support/GF65-Thin-9SE no Bluetooth drivers show up in Device Manager. What do I do? I just want to be able to connect my headphones to my computer again. If it helps I took a screenshot of the driver's information before uninstalling it:

[image]

Comment: See if any yellow or red marks beside Bluetooth in Device Manager to indicate a hardware error.

Comment: @John that's the thing, there's no Bluetooth category to begin with under device manager even after reinstalling. Even when showing hidden items no Bluetooth dropdown.

Comment: I think that you have a hardware issue with the Bluetooth, otherwise it would show up.

Comment: @John alright, just made a ticket with MSI, once this situation is all dealt with I'll update everybody here and resolve this question. Thanks!